# What to add to RSpec valid_attributes when it is validating related models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I am new to RSpec and Cucumber BDD development, and it's a big leap up.

Using rake generate scaffold model_name I've produced a ton of code that seems to make some sense, but that I'm not super confident with.

I was doing ok with RSpec until I added some database relationships and model validations, and then it all blew up and I don't really know what the best-practice or cleanest way of fixing it would be.

It's obvious my problem is that "valid attributes" needs to be defined with a foreign key linking to a valid Patient/Anaesthetist/Procedure/Surgeon, but I have no idea how I should write this in RSpec (maybe use FactoryGirl to generate a valid object of each model?)  The model RSpec code makes sense to me, but the controller code is out of my depth.

Seems like it should be do-able in one line, or maybe four lines (one for each object), but that should be it.

**The code**

```
#app/models/procedure.rb
class Procedure < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :patient
    belongs_to :surgeon
    belongs_to :anaesthetist
    belongs_to :hospital

    validates :patient_id, presence: true
    validates :surgeon_id, presence: true
    validates :anaesthetist_id, presence: true
    validates :hospital_id, presence: true
end
```

---

```
#spec/models/procedure_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe Procedure do

    it { should validate_presence_of(:patient_id) }
    it { should validate_presence_of(:surgeon_id) }
    it { should validate_presence_of(:anaesthetist_id) }
    it { should validate_presence_of(:hospital_id) }

end
```

---

```
#spec/controllers/procedures_controller_spec.rb
describe ProceduresController do

  # This should return the minimal set of attributes required to create a valid
  # Procedure. As you add validations to Procedure, be sure to
  # adjust the attributes here as well.
  let(:valid_attributes) { { "description" => "MyText" } }

  # This should return the minimal set of values that should be in the session
  # in order to pass any filters (e.g. authentication) defined in
  # ProceduresController. Be sure to keep this updated too.
  let(:valid_session) { {} }

  describe "GET index" do
    it "assigns all procedures as @procedures" do
      procedure = Procedure.create! valid_attributes
      get :index, {}, valid_session
      assigns(:procedures).should eq([procedure])
    end
  end

....

end
```

---

```
#Terminal output, note failures 4 and 5, there's about 10 more errors after that with the exact same cause
Failures:

  1) ProceduresController POST create with valid params redirects to the created procedure
     Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to(Procedure.last)
       Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>
     # ./spec/controllers/procedures_controller_spec.rb:80:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) ProceduresController POST create with valid params assigns a newly created procedure as @procedure
     Failure/Error: assigns(:procedure).should be_persisted
       expected persisted? to return true, got false
     # ./spec/controllers/procedures_controller_spec.rb:75:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) ProceduresController POST create with valid params creates a new Procedure
     Failure/Error: expect {
       count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0
     # ./spec/controllers/procedures_controller_spec.rb:67:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) ProceduresController PUT update with valid params redirects to the procedure
     Failure/Error: procedure = Procedure.create! valid_attributes
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Patient can't be blank, Surgeon can't be blank, Anaesthetist can't be blank, Hospital can't be blank
     # ./spec/controllers/procedures_controller_spec.rb:120:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  5) ProceduresController PUT update with valid params assigns the requested procedure as @procedure
     Failure/Error: procedure = Procedure.create! valid_attributes
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Patient can't be blank, Surgeon can't be blank, Anaesthetist can't be blank, Hospital can't be blank
     # ./spec/controllers/procedures_controller_spec.rb:114:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

etc.
```

---

**Fixing the problem**

My poor attempt at fixing the problem to give an idea of what I want to do.  The obvious solution is to somehow include a link to a valid Patient/Anaesthetist/Surgeon/Hospital in the valid attributes. I just need to know the proper RSpec/FactoryGirl/Rails (?) syntax to do something like this:

```
describe ProceduresController do

  # This should return the minimal set of attributes required to create a valid
  # Procedure. As you add validations to Procedure, be sure to
  # adjust the attributes here as well.
  FactoryGirl.create(:patient)
  FactoryGirl.create(:surgeon)
  FactoryGirl.create(:anaesthetist)
  FactoryGirl.create(:hospital)
  let(:valid_attributes) { { "description" => "MyText", "patient_id" => :patientid, "surgeon_id" => :surgeon.id, "anaesthetist_id" => :anaesthetist.id, "hospital_id" => :hospital.id } }

  # This should return the minimal set of values that should be in the session
  # in order to pass any filters (e.g. authentication) defined in
  # ProceduresController. Be sure to keep this updated too.
  let(:valid_session) { {} }

  describe "GET index" do
    it "assigns all procedures as @procedures" do
      procedure = Procedure.create! valid_attributes
      get :index, {}, valid_session
      assigns(:procedures).should eq([procedure])
    end
  end

...

end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the `POST create` and `PUT update` that's failing, and from the looks of things the records aren't being created because the valid_attributes aren't right, so you made a good conclusion!

You could approach it like this...

```
describe ProceduresController do
  # This should return the minimal set of attributes required to create a valid
  # Procedure. As you add validations to Procedure, be sure to
  # adjust the attributes here as well.
  let(:patient) { FactoryGirl.create(:patient) }
  let(:surgeon) { FactoryGirl.create(:surgeon) }
  let(:anaesthetist) { FactoryGirl.create(:anaesthetist)}
  let(:hospital) { FactoryGirl.create(:hospital) }
  let(:valid_attributes) { { "description" => "MyText", 
                             "patient_id" => patient.id, 
                             "surgeon_id" => surgeon.id, 
                             "anaesthetist_id" => anaesthetist.id, 
                             "hospital_id" => hospital.id } }
```

And I'd expect your create and update actions will work now.